# Neo4j - Get all parent nodes of a particular type of node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a newbie to property graph and database, have written simpler cypher queries. I have a model like below.

```
Project(is_lib: true|false)

Project[:HAS]-> Artifact[:HAS]-> Version

Version[:DEPENDS_ON]-> Version
```

**Example**

Project artifacts:

```
ProjectA(is_lib:false) -> ProjectA-ArtifactA -> [pa-v1.1, pa-v1.2]

ProjectB(is_lib:false) -> ProjectB-ArtifactB -> [pb-v2.0]

ProjectC(is_lib:true) -> ProjectC-ArtifactC -> [pc-v5.1, pc-v5.2]
```

Relations:

```
pa-v1.1 -> pb-v2.0 -> pc-v5.1

pa-v1.2 -> pc-v5.2
```

Above pc-v5.1 and pc-v5.2 is a **lib** type, which is a project property. I would like to get all the parents of project types **lib:true**.  **There could be a huge set of project in the database**.

So in the above example,  I am expecting below results.

```
pc-v5.1 has parents pa-v1.1, pb-v2.0. 
pc-v5.2 has parents pa-v1.2.
```

I would like to have a cypher query. I appreciate and would be grateful 
if anyone could direct towards me the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cypher query. For records if anyone looking for it. 
I have to look for performance aspects for this query though, not into performance aspects yet.

```
MATCH(j)-[:HAS]->(k)-[:HAS]->(l)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-(m)<-[:HAS]-(n)<-[:HAS]-(o)
WHERE o.is_lib=false
return m, l
```